# Uma linguagem subconjunto de uma linguagem livre de contexto é decidível?

Tags: teoria-da-computação, linguagens-formais

Se temos uma linguagem L livre de contexto e seja L' um subconjunto de L, então L' é decidível?

Comment: Só para dar mais contexto para quem for responder, imagina que temos uma LLC L de parênteses: todo parêntese aberto precisa ser fechado e não posso fechar algo que não foi aberto. Isso significa que `((()()))` é válido, porém `((())()))` não é válido. Agora imagina que eu pego essa linguagem e removo todas as palavras que contenham `(())` chamada L'; isso significa que `((())())` pertence a L, mas não a L', e `((()()))` pertence a ambas

Comment: O comentário acima foi para ilustrar que precisamos lidar com remoções infinitas de L para obter L', esqueci de adicionar essa motivação no meu comentário

Answer (score 7):

Imagine que temos uma linguagem `U` que seja indecidível. As palavras dela pertencem ao alfabeto Σ. Se `U` existir, então ela é uma sublinguagem de Σ*.

Tomemos agora a seguinte gramática `G` que produza `L(G)`:

```
S -> AS
S -> 
A -> el(Σ)
```

Onde `el(Σ)` é uma letra de Σ, qualquer uma. Essa linguagem equivale a Σ*. Portanto, se existir uma linguagem `U` para esse alfabeto, temos que `U` é subconjunto de `L(G)`. E `L(G)` é uma linguagem regular, portanto também é uma linguagem livre de contexto.